# RaspberryPi webserver with nginx and docker only displays Welcome to nginx

Tags: php, docker, nginx, raspberry-pi, webserver

I try to create a small webserver on my raspberry pi with docker.
This is my docker-compose file:

```
version: "3.6"
services:
  web:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    volumes:
      - /home/pi/testData/code:/var/www/html
      - /home/pi/testData/site.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/site.conf
    depends_on:
      - php

  php:
    image: php:7.4-fpm
    volumes:
      - /home/pi/testData/code:/var/www/html
```

And this my site.conf

```
server {
    index index.html index.php;
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    root /var/www/html;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
}
```

Inside of the folder `/home/pi/testData/code` is a file named `index.php` which just echos a Hello World.
So this file will be mapped into the Docker Container into the path `/var/www/html/` and inside of the `site.conf` is the root mentioned also to `/var/www/html`.
I also checked if the files are really available inside of the nginx container - both are.

So as I understand it: If I put an index-file inside of the `/var/www/html` folder of my nginx docker container, then this file should be displayed if I call the IP of my Raspberry pi on Port 8080.
But unfortunately I only receive the Welcome to Nginx Page.

Did I miss something or did I something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nginx will load configuration files found in `/etc/nginx/conf.d/` and their names ends with `.conf` as suffix in alphabetical order.

[image: /etc/nginx/nginx.conf]

Your configuration does have conflicting server name with the default configuration file of nginx. `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf`
you can check that by exec into nginx container and run `nginx -t` command to check the configuration for warnings and errors.

you should see something like:

```
[warn] 502#502: conflicting server name "localhost" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "localhost" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
```

**you should rename the default file to a something like `default.conf.old` or you can simply overwrite its contents with your configuration.**